# How to run an R script in crontab

Tags: r, cron

Using crontab -e I've tried:

```
* * * * *  Rscript /home/.../file.r
* * * * * /usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript /home/.../file.r
* * * * * /usr/bin/Rscript /home/.../file.r
* * * * * /home/.../foo.sh
```

where foo.sh contains:

```
sudo R CMD BATCH file.r
```

Just running $ ./foo.sh works.
$ R CMD BATCH file.r works.

Nothing I've tried in crontab works. Any ideas?

Comment: Try editing /etc/crontab instead.  I'm not sure sudo works from crontab -e

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to have the full path in your foo.sh:

```
sudo R CMD BATCH /home/.../file.r
```

I should also add that the first version worked for me, although I set it to a specific time rather than `* * * * *`

Comment: I've tried both  * * * * * and a specific time. Neither are doing anything.

Comment: If you change to a different directory and run `Rscript /home/.../file.r` from the command line does that work?

Comment: In case it is to do with file.R, have you tried creating a new simple test file, say test.R: `write.csv(rnorm(5), file="test.csv")` and setting crontab for that? Then you can see whether test.csv gets created.

Comment: Does file.R reference any paths itself?

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth here is CRANberries entry which has worked (multiple times) every day for 5+ years:

```
# every few hours, run cranberries
11 */2 * * *    edd     ~/cranberries/cranberries.r
```

Of note here are

1. The time specification, here 11 mins past the hour every two hours
2. The user
3. The complete path, using 'globbing' to expand `~` to `$HOME` for `edd`

and after that you just have to make sure the script is actually executable. Whether you use Rscript, littler or R BATCH CMD does not matter.

Comment: Correct, as `crontab -e` does not have the user field. I much prefer `/erc/crontab` for its simplicity.

Comment: I use crontab to run php scripts so I have a basic understanding of how it works. Still unsure why it won't work with R. I guess I'll be rewriting everything in php tomorrow.

Comment: Learn some basic debugging. Write an R one-liner script that just touches a file in `/tmp`. Get that to run. Then add more and more of your logic.  You really only need to sort out $PATH and permissions.

Comment: Solved it. What directory does the script run from? The issue was I was in the script I was sourcing another file in the same directory as the script but it seems that crontab runs everything from ~/. Sorry about being too irritated to debug, Ive been working on this for ~40 hours over the last 3 days and it was hugely frustrating that the biggest problem I had was crontabbing it.

Comment: Yes I have other crontab jobs that start `cd ~/foo/bar && ./somescript.r`.  This one does the `setwd()` as it starts...

Answer (score 1):

in my user level crontab I run a R script to collect tweets from various sources.

I used:
**`crontab -u myusername -e`**
added this to the end of my crontab file

**`0 0  * * * /home/bob/Documents/SWtweets/tweetbash.sh`**

I ran it as a user vs root, don't what difference it makes, but it only worked for me when I ran it at user level.

below is what I put in my tweetbash.sh shell script,
which tells the bash program to run the R script located at the path indicated.

**`#! /bin/bash
R CMD BATCH /home/bob/Documents/SWtweets/tweets.R`**

did **`chmod +x tweetbash.sh`**

it works for my purposes.

Bob