# Rstudio TaskscheduleR failure AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rstudio

I currently have an instance of Rstudio which runs on a private AWS server (which I built from using this AMI: http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/)

I am currently trying schedule a script to run, using the tasksheduleR package:

The script I am using to schedule is:

```
myscript <- system.file("extdata", "EG_pricedropAPI.R", package = "taskscheduleR")
cat(readLines(myscript), sep = "\n")

## Run script once at a specific timepoint (within 62 seconds)
runon <- format(Sys.time() + 62, "%H:%M")
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "testScript", rscript = myscript, 
                 schedule = "ONCE", starttime = runon)
```

Where 'EG_pricedropAPI.R' is a script I have written, in the 'extdata' location, which successfully runs when I run without taskscheduleR.

However every time I run this script, or a similar 'taskscheduler_create()' script I get the following error:

```
sh: 1: schtasks: not found
Error in system(cmd, intern = TRUE) : error in running command
```

Does anyone know what the fix for this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The taskcheduler package only works with the Windows task scheduler; the EC2 machine is running Linux. You won't be able to use it to schedule tasks on your RStudio Server.

Fortunately, it is pretty straightforward to set up an R script as a scheduled task on your EC2 Linux instance using cron. Use these links to get started:

https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/schedule-rscript-with-cron/

[Schedule R script using cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116411/schedule-r-script-using-cron)

[How to run an R script in crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014837/how-to-run-an-r-script-in-crontab)

Comment: Thank you! Have replicated my desired functionality through cron.